# Custom button to Jitsi React-SDK

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, frontend, web-frontend, jitsi

How can i make custom button for Jitsi React-SDK? It is possible to change a list of buttons in toolbar, but how to make my own , for example audio (mute/unmute) button or video (on/off)

It is important to use just ReactSDK  which is here - https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-react-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

We can create a CustomButton like below,

```
import React from 'react';
import { ToolbarButton } from '@jitsi/react-nativesdk';

const CustomButton = ({ icon, label, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <ToolbarButton
      iconName={icon}
      tooltip={label}
      onClick={onClick}
    />
  );
};

export default CustomButton;
```

And we can use it like below,

```
class MyApp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        isAudioMuted: false,
      };

   this.handleCustomButtonClick = this.handleCustomButtonClick.bind(this);
   }
  handleCustomButtonClick() {
    const isMuted = !this.state.isAudioMuted;
    this.setState({ isAudioMuted: isMuted });
    const command = isMuted ? 'muteAudio' : 'unmuteAudio';
    this.jitsiMeetView.executeCommand(command);
  }

 render(){

    const conferenceOptions = new 
    JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
      .setRoom('conf@emailid.id')
      .build();


      return <JitsiMeetView 
       onConferenceJoined={this.onConferenceJoined}
        onConferenceWillJoin={this.onConferenceWillJoin}
        options={conferenceOptions}
        toolbarButtons={[
          'camera',
           ...
           ...
          'videoquality',
          'custom-button', // Add your custom button here
        ]}
       <CustomButton
          icon="icon-mic"
          label="Mute/Unmute Audio"
        onClick={this.handleCustomButtonClick}
        />
      </JitsiMeetView>
  }
}
```

Comment: which event I have to handle in onClick for button ?

Comment: added the click event function in the component, attached that function on the button click event. Also added the state for isMuted to make toggling work